# Grails Hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate, grails, annotations

Can any1 explain me what hibernate annotations are for? I'm learning hibernate/grails and can't understand what it does. Check here: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html.

Comment: You're looking at very old 1.0 docs - you should be using http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/15.%20Grails%20and%20Hibernate.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate annotations are an alternative way to map your domain classes to the database. Generally, they should only be used if you have an existing Hibernate-annotated domain model that you want to use in a Grails app.

If you don't already have an existing domain model, then using the default GORM conventions is a more convenient way to map your domain classes to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate annotations are used to configure object-relational mapping of your objects, i.e. they define how your objects are persisted into the database. You can find more info on using them in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html).